# Divide a image of 512*256 into 2 images each of 256*256 using PIL

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have an image with dimensions 512 * 256 like,

[image]

The left section should be an input to the NN and the right section has to be the corresponding output. Hence, each of the images has dimensions of 256 * 256.

What I have done so far to split apart both the images:

```
image_dir = 'images'
image_filenames = os.listdir( image_dir )
for filename in image_filenames:
    image = Image \
        .open(os.path.join( image_dir, filename)) \
        .convert( 'RGB' )
    width , height = image.size
    x.append( np.asarray( image.crop( ( width , width/2 , width , width/2 )) ))
print( x )
```

The output shows an image which is empty and of size 0 * 0,

```
[array(<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=0x0 at 0x27049C55CF8>,
      dtype=object), array(<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=0x0 at 0x27049C55710>,
      dtype=object)]
```

> How can I perfectly split the 512 * 256 image into 2 images of 256 *256 without the problems above **using PIL or even NumPy** ?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to stick with PIL rather than just split using numpy?

Comment: Absolutely not. It will be helpful if you could give a solution in NumPy.

Answer (score 2):

As you imply you are not concerned if a solution uses **PIL** or not, here is one that just involves using **ImageMagick** at the command-line... no need to write any code:

```
magick image.jpg -crop 50x100% sub-%d.jpg
```

That gives you these two halves:

```
sub-0.jpg
sub-1.jpg
```

**ImageMagick** is included in most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows. If you are using v6 or older, replace `magick` with `convert`.

---

If you have lots to do, you can use **GNU Parallel** to get them all done in parallel like this:

```
parallel 'magick {} -crop 50x100% {.}-sub-%d.jpg' ::: *.jpg
```

So, if you started with `fred.jpg` and `bill.jpg` you would get this:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff      13924 13 Jun 16:52 fred-sub-0.jpg
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff      11650 13 Jun 16:52 fred-sub-1.jpg
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff      13924 13 Jun 16:52 bill-sub-0.jpg
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff      11650 13 Jun 16:52 bill-sub-1.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks for telling about ImageMagick, @Mark Setchell

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am missing something, and if you are willing to use numpy, it should be as simple as:

```
import numpy as np

# Create example image
A = np.random.random((512, 256, 3))

# Split the image into two images
A1 = A[:256]
A2 = A[256:]

print(A.shape)
print(A1.shape)
print(A2.shape)
```

This just splits on the first dimension.

A more general solution would be:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.random((512, 256, 3))

A1 = A[:A.shape[0]//2]
A2 = A[A.shape[0]//2:]

print(A.shape)
print(A1.shape)
print(A2.shape)
```

In this case the `//2` is for integer division.  Then if `A = np.random.random((512, 256, 3)` the result will be:

```
(512, 256, 3)
(256, 256, 3)
(256, 256, 3)
```

And if `A = np.random.random((513, 256, 3)` the result will be:

```
(513, 256, 3)
(256, 256, 3)
(257, 256, 3)
```

In the case of an odd number for the first dimension, you will have to make a decision as to handle the difference in image size.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will run it and accept the answer if it works.